# Javascript function with a callback that passes the initiated object as a parameter

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am trying to extend some existing functionality so it has a callback function that passes the original object as a parameter, or at least any public variables that is stored in a smaller object, how can I achieve this?

This is a simplified version of the file I am working with, a class would be contained in a variable

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>

var foo = new Foo ({
    arg1:1,
    onComplete: function(){
        alert("complete " + total);
    }
});

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The function / class looks similar to this

```
function Foo(options) {
    // private
    var number1_ = options.arg1;
    var number2_ = 10;
    var total_ = number1_ + number2_;

    // public
    this.total = total_;

    (function Foo() {
        if (options) {
            if (options.onComplete && typeof (options.onComplete) === "function") {

                // how do I pass Foo or an object of selected variables here?
                options.onComplete();
            }
        }
    })();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out :)

```
function Foo(options) {
    // private
    var number1_ = options.arg1,
        number2_ = 10,
        total_ = number1_ + number2_;
    // public
    this.total = total_;

    (function Magazine( that ) {

        (options.onComplete || function(){}).call( that );

    })(this);
}

var foo = new Foo({
    arg1: 1,
    onComplete: function() {

        alert("complete " + this.total);
    }
});
```

Live demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/P3bzM/

Comment: Super, I figured it would be passing this (or in 'this' demo's case, 'that') but I was not familiar with the call or apply functionality.  ta

Comment: You can also try without `that`. `(function Magazine(  ) {

        (options.onComplete || function(){}).call( this );

    }).call(this)`

Answer (score 2):

```
(function Magazine() {
    if (options) {
        if (options.onComplete && typeof (options.onComplete) === "function") {

            // if you want `this === the foo instance` in the function:
            options.onComplete.call(this);
            // otherwise just pass it as an argument:
            options.onComplete(this);
        }
    }
}).call(this);
```

Comment: That's just _too_ bloated. Why is all this function magic there in the first place, when it is not needed? `(function ...).call(this)` inside the constructor looks like `if (false === ((i>=10) === true))` kind of thing used instead `if (i<10)` to me.

Comment: Why would I rewrite this guy's whole code if copy&paste with a minor change is all needed to answer his question?

Comment: Removing first and last line of your portion is a complete rewrite?

Comment: It might be very well possible that the actual code contains more lines and this was just a shortened version though

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>

var foo = new Foo ({
    arg1:1,
    onComplete: function(total){
        alert("complete " + total);
    }
});

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>


function Foo(options) {
    // private
    var number1_ = options.arg1;
    var number2_ = 10;
    var total_ = number1_ + number2_;

    // public
    this.total = total_;

    (function Magazine() {
        if (options) {
            if (options.onComplete && typeof (options.onComplete) === "function") {

                // how do I pass Foo or an object of selected variables here?
                options.onComplete(total_);
            }
        }
    })();
}
```

Look for word "total" to see the changes.

Comment: This won't work since `this` is not referring to the instance anymore.

Comment: Fixed. BTW why did you encapsulate using Magazine closure? No need for it, simply put the if statement there, without the `(function ...)()` overhead (then you could use `this.total` btw).

Comment: Thanks for this, the file seems a bit overkill and I'll be simplifying it where possible, Magazine was a typo for the question I posted (should have been Foo), but I don't quite understand the whole file yet so I don't know if it's needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

You've got several ways to achieve this.

1. Simply add parameters when calling your callback:

   ```
   if (options.onComplete && typeof (options.onComplete) === "function") {

       // how do I pass Foo or an object of selected variables here?
       options.onComplete(this.number1_, this.number2_, this.total_);
   }
   ```
2. Use .call() or .apply() javascript method to set the context of the callback (what will be `this` within the callback)

   ```
   if (options.onComplete && typeof (options.onComplete) === "function") {

       // how do I pass Foo or an object of selected variables here?
       options.onComplete.apply(this);
       // options.onComplete.call(this);
   }
   ```

   Both methods works the same way, they simply differ in the way you pass arguments to the method. Read [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) to get more info